# Underlined labels in the description environment

Tags: labels, description

How can the `description` environment be modified so that it uses underlined labels instead of the default bold texts? It would be better if I can do that globally not just for one time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

Redefine `\descriptionlabel`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace{\labelsep}\normalfont\underline{#1}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[abc] def
\item[ghi] lmn
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that underlining is not a good typographic device.